# When running WebDriver with opera browser, getting message "Starting OperaDriver 2.30 on port 21389 Only local connections are allowed."

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

When I try to run my automation Script on opera browser. It gives me this message.

> Starting OperaDriver 2.30 on port 21389 Only local connections are
>   allowed.

Version Details

> System:   `Windows 8.1 64-bit` 
>  Selenium: `3.6.0` 
>  Java
>   Version: `1.8.0_144` 
>  TestNg: `6.9.12` 
>  Opera Browser:
>   `48.0.2685.50 (PGO)`
>  Opera Driver: `2.30`  or `2.29`

Visit this [url](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases), to download the latest Opera driver 
`operadriver_win64.zip`

**Note:** When I execute my test suite using same configuration on `chrome` and `firefox` browser. My Test suite is working fine on both the browsers.

Every time when I try to run my automation script on `opera browser`, It gives me same error but everytime `port number` is getting changed.

Can anyone help me on this issue?